# iOS OnVolumeChange or equivalent event

Tags: javascript, ios, events

Trying to make it quick here.  Besides setting up an event listener for `<audio>` or `<video>`, does anyone know of a way to detect changes to amplitude initiated by the volume rocker switch on the device?

With all the problems in making volume controllable with a slider on-page, I'd like to let the user adjust volume with the rocker, but to provide a graphical representation of the level on-page.

Thanks

EDIT: Pure JS, please.  I do not wish to impart anything like a Sencha lib or Phone Gap or anything.

Comment: Just wondering, but why reinvent the wheel when an open-source solution is available?

Comment: I don't want to expend time familiarizing myself with PhoneGap

Comment: Then you will end up expending time developing your own custom solution which is certainly not going to be trivial.

Comment: I understand that, but I figured my line of questioning would probably be a good indicator and how unfamiliar I am with iOS.  From what I've read, it seems as though the "System" or MPVolume is not available to the document, so relying solely on JS to ascertain this value is out of the question

Comment: If you are adamant about creating your own implementation, then I would suggest taking a look at how PhoneGap accomplished this feature. You can then use that knowledge as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Take a look into `AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification`.</strike>

**Updated javascript solution to question asked**:

There is a free/open-source framework called [PhoneGap](http://zsprawl.com/iOS/2012/03/ios-volume-control-in-phonegap/) that allows one to hook into iOS’s native volume control from your javascript functions.

Comment: That would work great if they were using Objective-C, but according to the question's tags, Rob is trying to do this in javscript.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific.  No frameworks or adjuncts desired for this solution.  Thanks